# Gtest filter tests by type parameter

Tags: c++, googletest

I have a type parametrized test fixture and I want to filter my tests by the type parameter name. Let's look at the example:

Suppose I have a simple type parametrized GTest test fixture like this:

```
template <typename T>
class TestWorkers : public Test {
public:
    ~TestWorkers()
    {
        // Tear down
    }
};
```

I want to test many *workers* that have a similar interface

```
struct Worker1 {
    int do_work() {
        return 42;
    }
};

struct Worker2 {
    int do_work() {
        return -42;
    }
};
```

I also have a bunch of tests for my workers:

```
typedef Types<Worker1, Worker2> TestTypes;

TYPED_TEST_CASE(TestWorkers, TestTypes);

TYPED_TEST(TestWorkers, ReturnsEvenNumber)
{
    // ...
}

TYPED_TEST(TestWorkers, ReturnsAlwaysTheSameNumber)
{
    // ...
}
```

I want to run my tests with different configurations like this:

1. Run all tests
2. Run all tests only for `Worker1`
3. Run only `ReturnsEvenNumber` test and only for `Worker1`

I understand how to run a single test case for all type parameters (this can be achieved with `--gtest_filter` option). But I can't find a way to run all test cases for only one type parameter.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is no such ability in the GTest at the moment. I implement [simple extensions](https://gist.github.com/Umqra/189855b2d806b1b7395cd2475e7c0a90) of the default `TYPED_TEST(...)` macro, that adds parameter name to full test name.

Now I can use `TYPED_TEST_EXTNAME(...)` macro instead the default one:

```
TYPED_TEST(TestWorkers, ReturnsEvenNumber) { /* ... */ }
TYPED_TEST(TestWorkers, ReturnsAlwaysTheSameNumber) { /* ... */ }
```

And the list of all tests will be the next:

```
$ ./tests --gtest_list_tests
TestWorkers/0.  # TypeParam = Worker1
  ReturnsEvenNumber[Worker1]
  ReturnsAlwaysTheSameNumber[Worker1]
TestWorkers/1.  # TypeParam = Worker2
  ReturnsEvenNumber[Worker2]
  ReturnsAlwaysTheSameNumber[Worker2]
```

Here I can easily filter tests by the parameter name:

```
./tests --gtest_filter="*[Worker1]*"
```